# Netflix GraphQL DGS Codegen "dgsCodegen" not generating classes from schemas in external dependency

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

Don't know whether my expectation is just plain unrealistic, or whether the DGS documentation is just really incomprehensible - cos this seems simple enough, however none of what was described in [this section of the Netflix DGS Docs](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/#generating-code-from-external-schemas-in-jars:%7E:text=in%20the%20module.-,Generating%20code%20from%20external%20schemas%20in%20JARs,-%C2%B6) works as expected;

[Netflix DGS Docs](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/#generating-code-from-external-schemas-in-jars:%7E:text=in%20the%20module.-,Generating%20code%20from%20external%20schemas%20in%20JARs,-%C2%B6) says;

> You can also specify external dependencies containing schemas to use
> for generation by declaring it as a dependency in the `dgsCodegen`
> configuration. The plugin will scan all `.graphql` and `.graphqls` files
> and generate those classes under the same `build/generated` directory.
> ***This is useful if you have external dependencies containing some
> shared types that you want to add to your schema for code generation***.
> Note that this does NOT affect your project's schema, and is only for
> code generation.

Example:

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    dgsCodegen 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:example-schema:x.x.x'
}
```

---

So to work with this, I have two projects structured as follows:

***shared-schemas*** project structure

```
shared-schemas
    |
    --- src/main/resources/schema
    |                       |
    |                       --- shared-models.graphqls
    |
    --- build.gradle
    |
    --- settings.gradle
```

***shared-schemas*** `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id "java-library"
}
group = 'com.shared.library'

// ... other configs
```

***shared-library*** `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'shared-schemas'
```

---

***application*** project structure

```
application
    |
    --- src/main/resources/schema
    |                       |
    |                       --- application-models.graphqls
    |
    --- build.gradle
    |
    --- settings.gradle
```

***application*** `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.netflix.dgs.codegen" version "6.1.3"
}

// ... other configs

dependencies {
    dgsCodegen 'com.shared.library:shared-schemas:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

generateJava {
    schemaPaths = ["src/main/resources/schema"] // List of directories containing schema files
    packageName = "com.application.graphql.schemas" // The package name to use to generate sources
    generateClient = true // Enable generating the type safe query API
}
```

Then I carry out the following gradle build steps;

1. cd into **shared-schemas** then `./gradlew pulishToMavenLocal` to install the library locally
2. cd into **application** then `./gradlew clean build` to build the application which references the library as a dependency.

---

After these, the ***application*** build was successful, and GraphQL models defined inside `application-models.graphqls` are all created into `build/generated` folder. However the GraphQL models that were defined in `shared-models.graphqls` (within the ***shared-schemas*** library) aren't generated, and aren't inside the `build/generated` folder [as the DGS docs suggest](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/#generating-code-from-external-schemas-in-jars:%7E:text=in%20the%20module.-,Generating%20code%20from%20external%20schemas%20in%20JARs,-%C2%B6).

Could someone kindly point me towards what's being done incorrectly here?